# Dispatcher forward displaying deleted data on new page?

Tags: php, phalcon

I am deleting a "mob" then redirecting to the index page. My problem is that if I use `$this -> dispatcher -> forward()` when I get to the index page (which displays all mobs) the deleted mob will still display due to `forward()`'s behavior of not refreshing the page.

Usually I solve this problem by using `response-> redirect()`, however I cannot use it here as I use dispatcher to send params like this.

```
return $this -> dispatcher -> forward(array('controller' => 'mob', 'action' => 'index', "params" =>array("alert" => "Mob deleted.")));
```

My question is, what is the best practice to send my parameters but also refresh the page so deleted objects aren't rendered after dispatching?

Answer (score 0):

> I get to the index page (which displays all mobs) the deleted mob will
>   still display due to forward()'s behavior of not refreshing the page.

That is not entirely true and this has to do with caching database calls during the request or you simply not refreshing the displayed data. I'd say more if you provided the code for both actions, but this shouldn't be hard to figure out on your own. Your index action must load the model set every time its called, so if you have deleted a model in the forwarding action, there should be no reason for that model to be present in the consecutive load in the forwarded action.

Generally forwarding would be better technique than reloading the page – you don't make another request to the server for no real reason. If you need to use redirection there's a number of ways you can pass alerts between the pages, e.g., storing the alert queue in the session or database. Phalcon has the [Flash](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/flash.html) component for displaying flashing messages, which allows to use the session approach.